# Placing Works Cited (or references) in another document

Tags: bibliographies, pdfpages

I have a document which uses the standard `\cite` to cite a reference.  At the end of my document, I have a `\bibliography` to place the **References** section there.  However, the fellowship I'm applying to asks to submit the essay and references in different documents.  Is there any way I can split the two from each other.  That is to say, have the essay on one document, and the references on another?

There is one way I can think of doing this but it doesn't use LaTeX.  I have a software that can print anything to PDF.  I can use it to print the essay pages to a PDF and name it `Essay.pdf`, and then use it to print only the references seciton to PDF and name it `Works_Cited.pdf`.

I didn't know what Tags this question fell under, so I apologize if I chose the wrong tags.

Comment: i'd suggest using the author-year style of citing so that the cross-references are somewhat comprehensible.  run the job through completely enough times to get the citations resolved.  before the bibliography, insert `\clearpage` and reset the page counter to start at 1.  then use `pdfpages` to split the pdf file into the required two parts, and rename as appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: could you please elaborate more on how to use `pdfpages` to split the pdf file into two parts? That's really what I need!

Comment: apologies.  unfortunately, i have gotten `pdfpages` mixed up with something else; `pdfpages` is used to insert selected pages from another existing pdf file into a latex document.  it's not designed to split pdf files.  an approach that should work is to output your complete document to a dvi file, then use the `dvipdfm` program to split it into multiple pdf files.  the manual for `dvipdfm` (`texdoc dvipdfm` if you are working with a tex live installation) is very clear.  the options `-o` (output file name) and `-s` (page ranges) are the ones you need.

Comment: Interesting!  I'll look into that ASAP! Maybe submit an answer so I could mark it correct if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it could be a simple job for  `biblatex`.

Create a file (`file1.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{yourbibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

Your essay with normal citation commands \cite{ref1,ref2}

\end{document}
```

then you can run `bibexport yourfile`  to create a `bib` files with only the references cited in `file1` and then use the following file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibexport.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: How will it know which references were cited in my file?

Comment: And wouldn't the order of the bib items in the .bib file matter in this scenario?

Comment: The order of the bib items in the `.bib` files does not matter.  To know which references are cited the solution suggest to use the program `bibexport` which creates a new `bib` file with the references cited in the first file.

Comment: I get undefined control sequence `\addbibresource`

Comment: Have you inserted `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`?

Comment: I did, yes.  Working with TeXShop on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Comment: Can you try with a new file with just the first code snippet? (replacing `mybibliographyfile.bib` with the `bib` file you use, include the `bib` extension in the file name)

Comment: I think I'm just going to use the PDF printing method.  It's silly to print a PDF to a PDF, but it is what it is.  I'm honestly a little tired of this issue.  I'll mark your answer correct even though it didn't really work for me.  LaTeX can really be a headache sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

If you use a citation style that doesn't enumerate the citations such as with natbib and [the authoryear option](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php), then it becomes easy. Use your citations as normal.

Write your document as usual, with your citations. Don't include the bibliography. In separate (empty) LaTeX document, use \nocite{*} somewhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to use all entries in your bibfile, and have a bibliography as normal. This document will now contain only a bibliography with all of the references in your chosen .bib file(s).

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{what_you_want}
\bibliography{your_bib_file}
\end{document}
```

You might want to check out the [natbib documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do use a citation format that does enumerate the citations.  I'm restricted to this format.  For example, blah blah blah [1], another study found that blah blah [2].